# No data when passing an object to a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you pass an object to a directive? I'm trying to access `users` in my directive's `scope` without success. This is what I've tried:

In my controller I set an array of `users` to a scope:

```
$scope.users = payload.data.results;
```

Then I want to pass that object to my directive as an attribute:

```
<display test123='users'></display>
```

The directive function:

```
function ListDisplay() {
    var directive = {
      replace: 'true',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        test123: '='
      },
      controller: ListDisplayController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      link: ListDisplayLinkFunc
    };

    return directive;


    function ListDisplayController($scope) {
      console.log($scope.test123);

    }

    function ListDisplayLinkFunc(scope, elem, attr) {

      console.log(scope.test123);
    }
  }
```

But when I try to console out `scope.data` I get undefined.

Comment: I think data is related to html5 attribute.try to use some other name.It might help

Comment: thanks @RIYAJKHAN I've changed it to ``test123`` and still get undefined. :(

Comment: Can we have sample plunker?

Comment: Is `payload` in `payload.data.results` is a promise?

Comment: Please share our dir def

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal no its the results of a promise i.e. ``.then(function (payload) {``

Comment: It looks like the answer as a combination of both @valepu and Shashank Agrawal answers, what to do, can I accept both answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `controllerAs: 'vm'` and `bindToController: true`, this means that the values you pass in the scope are assigned to a variable called `vm`

Try this:

```
function ListDisplayController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log(vm.test123);

}
```

to handle using "bindToController" in the link function you can do

```
function ListDisplayLinkFunc(scope, elem, attr) {

  console.log(scope.vm.test123);
}
```

you can see it in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/r2wuTE5oafYeu8h3Cjio?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `payload.data.results` is a result of an AJAX call. Your directive is being compiled before your AJAX call is succeeded. So you need to register a watch in your controller to get the value when the data is updated via the AJAX call.

```
function ListDisplayLinkFunc(scope, elem, attr) {
    console.log(scope.test123);

    scope.$watch('test123', function(newValue) {
         if (newValue) {
            console.log('Updated users in the directive', newValue);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like the answer as a combination of both @valepu and Shashank Agrawal answers, what to do????

Comment: Well both were the issue, first the data had not finished being loaded and then ``controllerAs``  assigned it to a variable called vm.